# How to find approximation for $f(n)=f(n-1)+n\log n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I need to find an approximation for the recurrence relation: $$f(n)=f(n-1)+n\log n \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}$$  (to be more precise I need to find an upper bound).

I tried dividing the LHS and RHS by $n!$ for $n \ge 2$ ($n=1$ is the base case where $f(1) = 0$):
$$
{f(n) \over n!}={f(n-1) \over n!}+{n\log n \over n!} = {\log n \over (n-1)!}+{\log n \over (n-2)!}+...+{\log n \over 1!} = \sum_{i=2}^n {\log n \over (n-i)!}=
$$
$$
 = \log n\sum_{i=2}^n {1 \over (n-i)!} 
$$

At the point the expression $\sum_{i=2}^n {1 \over (n-i)!} $  reminds of the series of $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {x^i \over i!} =e^x$   where in our case $x=1$. I'm wondering if we can arrive to the conclusion that:
$$
{f(n) \over n!} \le \log(n) \cdot e \qquad \Rightarrow f(n) \le \frac{\log(n) \cdot e}{n!}
$$

Comment: Your computations do not hold because the $f(n-1)$ term on the RHS is $\frac{f(n-1)}{n!}$ instead of $\frac{f(n-1)}{(n-1)!}$. For an upper bound, try $$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nk\log k\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^nk\log n=\ldots$$ which is of the right order.

Comment: Something appears wrong, as $f(2) = 2 \log 2$ and $f$ is increasing, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e \log n}{n !} = 0$.

Comment: @Did I realize that my RHS is incorrect but I didn't understand why. Can you please show how the RHS should've looked like?

Comment: Again: If $$f(n)=f(n-1)+n\log n$$ then $$
{f(n) \over n!}={f(n-1) \over n!}+{n\log n \over n!}$$ but you are iterating the wrong relation $$
{f(n) \over n!}={f(n-1) \over (n-1)!}+{n\log n \over n!}$$

Comment: @Yos Yes -- as written in my first comment, if I may add...

Comment: ((Comment by the OP insta-deleted.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** We may rewrite $f$ more explicitly as
$$f(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n k \log k .$$
Then, since the function $x \mapsto x \log x$ is increasing, we may bound $f$ above by $$\int_a^{b(n)} x \log x \,dx$$
for suitable $a, b(n)$.

Comment: @ Travis: I guess the solution is much simpler than I thought. Just to make sure I understand correctly, the recurrence is equivalent to $n \log n + (n-1) \log(n-1) + (n-2) \log(n-2) +...+1 \cdot \log(1)$?

Comment: Yes, and it's straightforward to prove that by induction.